# Get week number in given data range for specific month in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to display weekly user record based on given date ,
let's suppose I am giving date range `'2014-01-24'`,
this date which week it will take

example: week 1, week 2, week 3, week 4,

I am using query like,

```
select weekday(date);
```

Comment: `'2014-01-24'` is ONE date, NOT a range.

Comment: pardon me, what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

[WEEK(date[,mode])](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) This function returns the week number for date

```
 SELECT WEEK('2014-01-24') as numberofweeks;
```

## [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e7a9f/4)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[**WEEK(date[,mode])**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

This function returns the week number for date. The two-argument form of WEEK() enables you to specify whether the week starts on Sunday or Monday and whether the return value should be in the range from 0 to 53 or from 1 to 53.

```
mysql> SELECT WEEK('2014-01-24');
-> 3
```

i.e; **Week 3**

Answer (score 0):

Use [Week Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) `WEEK(date[,mode])` available with `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WEEK('2014-01-24');
+--------------------+
| WEEK('2014-01-24') |
+--------------------+
|                  3 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but I think you need to use the "DAYOFMONTH" function instead of "WEEKDAY". Once you have the DAYOFMONTH, use the division operator to find out which week # you are in.

For example:

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH('2007-02-22');
```

Would return 22.

```
22 / 7 = 3, so you are in week 3.
```

EDIT: This answer is based on finding the week number of the month given. The other answers show the "WEEK" function, which would give the week number in regards to the year given.

Answer (score 0):

I made something, maybe this can help you but the number of weeks varies according to the week begins, example: Here in Brazil, the week starts in Sunday. So take a look if this can solve your problem.

```
SET @date:='2014-08-31';
SELECT 
    @first := date_add(
        date_add(
            LAST_DAY(@date),
            interval 1 DAY
        ),
        interval -1 MONTH
    ) AS first_day,
    @date,
    -- EXAMPLE 1
    WeekofYear(@date),
    WeekofYear(@first),
    WeekofYear(@date)-(WeekofYear(@first)-1) Num_Week,
    -- EXAPLE 2 - Works in Brazil perfectly
    Week(@date),
    Week(@first),
    Week(@date)-(Week(@first)-1) Num_Week_Brazil
```